# Create ListView in Fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, listview

I'm trying to create a ListView on Fragments in Kotlin.

I have code that works in the Activity itself, but it doesn't work in Fragment

I'm getting a few errors:
Unresolved reference: findViewById
Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected

In the search I found information that in ArrayAdapter I should pass not this, but activity, but it does not work

```
var carList = ArrayList<String>()
carList.add("2131231")
carList.add("31312313123")
val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, carList)
listView.adapter = ArrayAdapter(FragmentSearch, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, carList)
```

What do I need to fix to make the code work for Fragment?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I'm getting a few errors:
Unresolved reference: findViewById
Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected

In the search I found information that in ArrayAdapter I should pass not this, but activity, but it does not work

Comment: I fixed the error with Unresolved reference: findViewById, but now I don't understand what to specify as the first argument in ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `ArrayAdapter` is a `Context`.

You are in `Fragment`. `Fragment` is not a `Context`.

But `Fragment` *has* a `Context` via the `Activity` it is attached to.

```
val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, carList)
```

Comment: When I change this exercise to, I get an error:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See the log for more details

Comment: OK. That has nothing to do with the question you asked. And without more information (like the log info it's telling you to look at), I don't know what to tell you.